# Cloud9 IDE can't find aws-amplify module, as per initial steps in the tutorial/walkthrough

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cloud9

I followed the [official tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/start/getting-started/setup/) and I did the `npm install aws-amplify` step, seemingly successfully. When I then edit the src/main.tsx as indicated, a number of errors pop up. I could resolve a few of them (changing compiler settings in the tsconfig.json, for example), but it's not clear why it can't find the aws-amplify module (it's there).

- I tried npm audit fix --force, as suggested in [another thread on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62324774/aws-amplify-tutorial-fail-to-start-the-client-app).
- I have removed node_modules and reinstalled.
- I have removed the entire project and started over.

This should be reproducible by following the above tutorial with a fresh Cloud9 instance.

It's extremely frustrating that simply following the steps in an official tutorial results in so many problems.

[image]

I [tried asking this last night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78235932/aws-amplify-tutorial-failure-cannot-find-aws-amplify-despite-it-being-present#78235932), in a much more verbose way, that seemingly won't get a response. So, I need to close that out, I'll have to look into the best way to do that, since I don't want to mark it as answered when it hasn't been.